# Map Object of Objects without knowing Object Key - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, react-native

I need to get "primarySprayCanRGB" and "primarySprayCanHighLightRGB" from each individual object in the object and add them to the array.
But I don't know the individual object keys. => The paint names are different.
I'm working in React Native

for example get: [["#000000", "#131313"],["#292b2d", "#7b7d80"],["#6b0913", "#bc3038"],...]

**The code I have so far, to get the data to add to the array, but the code returns only the first oibject because the id is not incremented :**

```
//data == object.paints
//loadinga == false => when data is ready to use
{!loadinga && data.map((object,id) => console.log(object[id].primarySprayCan.primarySprayCanRGB))}
```

**Link to JSON file:**

https://cdn.imagin.studio/getPaintSwatches?customer=imagin&make=tesla&paints=pbsb,pmng,ppmr,ppsb,ppsw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```js
const extractData = data => Object.values(data.paints).map(({primarySprayCan}) => [primarySprayCan.primarySprayCanRGB, primarySprayCan.primarySprayCanHighLightRGB])

const data = {
  "make": "tesla",
  "paints": {
    "pbsb": {
      "paintId": "pspc0004",
      "paintDescription": "",
      "primarySprayCan": {
        "sprayCanId": "spc0004",
        "paintType": "uni",
        "primarySprayCanRGB": "#000000",
        "primarySprayCanHighLightRGB": "#131313",
        "colourCluster": "black"
      }
    },
    "pmng": {
      "paintId": "pspc0239",
      "paintDescription": "",
      "primarySprayCan": {
        "sprayCanId": "spc0239",
        "paintType": "mic",
        "primarySprayCanRGB": "#292b2d",
        "primarySprayCanHighLightRGB": "#7b7d80",
        "colourCluster": "grey"
      }
    },
    "ppmr": {
      "paintId": "pspc0107",
      "paintDescription": "",
      "primarySprayCan": {
        "sprayCanId": "spc0107",
        "paintType": "mic",
        "primarySprayCanRGB": "#6b0913",
        "primarySprayCanHighLightRGB": "#bc3038",
        "colourCluster": "red"
      }
    },
    "ppsb": {
      "paintId": "pspc0266",
      "paintDescription": "",
      "primarySprayCan": {
        "sprayCanId": "spc0266",
        "paintType": "mic",
        "primarySprayCanRGB": "#101b47",
        "primarySprayCanHighLightRGB": "#254e9d",
        "colourCluster": "blue"
      }
    },
    "ppsw": {
      "paintId": "pspc0109",
      "paintDescription": "",
      "primarySprayCan": {
        "sprayCanId": "spc0109",
        "paintType": "pearl",
        "primarySprayCanRGB": "#b4b4b4",
        "primarySprayCanHighLightRGB": "#b4b4b4",
        "colourCluster": "grey"
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(extractData(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map through the values of the `paints` objects using the `Object.values()` function. then select the values you want to extract from it.

```
Object.values(data).map({ primarySprayCan } => {
    return [ primarySprayCan['primarySprayCanRGB'], primarySprayCan['primarySprayCanHighLightRGB'] ]
});
```